# Android Sqlite update get called but no change occurs

Tags: android, sql

```
public void updateEntry(long id, String perce) 
{
ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
editCon.put(KEY_PERCENT, perce);
open();
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
close();
}
```

Above is my code inside database and it is called to update 1st entry in my activity as

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long i=0;
        objectDBAdapter.updateEntry(i, "2%" );
    }
});
```

My problem is even if update method is called no change occurs in database. Please tell me where is the problem.The same update code works in a sample application, but i want to call it as stated.

Comment: what error does it return in logcat?

Comment: are you able to browse the database with an app? You should check if the _id is really 0

Comment: @Waqas no error returned if i put System.out.println("update method called"+i+"  " +_percent); inside update method it will print corresponding values.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i can browse and delete rows created too, only problem is is in update method

Comment: is it possible to show me more code from Your database class? If You are sure that You transmitted the right _id, then we have to show where this issue come from.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs My full database is here [link](http://www.beetxt.com/khY/)

Comment: Could You please try some? Insert some new values into Your db and then, check the _id of every entry with a logcat output. Is the _id allways the same?

Comment: _id always same first one has value 0

Comment: This Question can be closed problem solved by recreating database